# Передача параметров в функции php

Tags: функции, php

Замечается мне всё чаще и чаще в разных фреймворках такая конструкция передачи параметров в о внутрь функции function foo(SimpleParams, $params){}
не могу понять что значит первая строка в скобка, что это?

Comment: Может быть у вас в скобках запятая лишняя?
Конструкция `foo(SimpleParams $params)` означает что входящий параметр `$params` должен быть `instanceof SimpleParams`, т.е. экземпляром класса `SimpleParams`.

Comment: И всё? Спасибо!